# apache camel unresolved constraint in bundle when installing in apache karaf

Tags: java, xml, apache, maven, apache-camel

I'm new to Apache camel und just tried to build a Route with the RouteBuilder but as soon as I got a class extending RouterBuilder I get this error when i try to install that bundle in Apache karaf:

```
2015-09-08 14:54:49,227 | WARN  | raf-3.0.4/deploy | fileinstall
      | 7 - org.apache.felix.fileinstall - 3.5.0 | Error while starting bundle:
file:/C:/apache-karaf-3.0.4/deploy/osgi-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle osgi [91]: U
nable to resolve 91.0: missing requirement [91.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.w
iring.package=org.apache.camel.builder)(version>=2.14.0)(!(version>=3.0.0)))
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:397
4)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.2.1.jar:]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2037)[org.apa
che.felix.framework-4.2.1.jar:]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:955)[org.
apache.felix.framework-4.2.1.jar:]
        at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.startBundle(Di
rectoryWatcher.java:1245)[7:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.5.0]
        at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.startBundles(D
irectoryWatcher.java:1217)[7:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.5.0]
        at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.doProcess(Dire
ctoryWatcher.java:509)[7:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.5.0]
        at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.process(Direct
oryWatcher.java:358)[7:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.5.0]
        at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.run(DirectoryW
atcher.java:310)[7:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.5.0]
```

Right now I only got those 2 Classes

```
package osgi;

import org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;

public class Activator implements BundleActivator {

    public void start(BundleContext context) {
        System.out.println("Starting the bundle");
    }

    public void stop(BundleContext context) {
        System.out.println("Stopping the bundle");
    }

}

package osgi;

import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;

public class TimerRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

and this is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <!--

        Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
        contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
        this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
        The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
        (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
        the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

            http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

        Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
        distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
        WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
        See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
        limitations under the License.
    -->

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>osgi</groupId>
    <artifactId>osgi</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>bundle</packaging>

    <name>osgi Bundle</name>
    <description>osgi OSGi bundle project.</description>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.14.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.7</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                        <Bundle-Version>${project.version}</Bundle-Version>
                        <Bundle-Activator>osgi.Activator</Bundle-Activator>
                        <Export-Package>
                            osgi*;version=${project.version}
                        </Export-Package>
                        <Import-Package>
                            *
                        </Import-Package>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: What's your OSGI bundle with number 91? Have you checked already the missing requirement for `org.apache.camel.builder`?

Comment: I only got one OSGi bundle which is the one consisting out of those 3 parts - that is the one with number 91. `org.apache.camel.builder` is inside the camel-core dependency I got in the xml

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing **camel-core** dependency in your Karaf installation. If you check the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file in your osgi-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar bundle you can see that there is line in Import-Packages section that says **org.apache.camel.builder** with all other packages that are required for your bundle to run.

Now when you deploy your bundle all those imports in the manifest file must be satisfied, otherwise you get those bundle wiring exceptions. Since you have camel-core in your pom.xml (more precisely since you have imports in your Java code to camel-core classes) you must have those classes also present in Karaf. Your own classes will be inside that bundle jar since you have defined:

```
<Export-Package>
    osgi*;version=${project.version}
</Export-Package>
```

Karaf will provide org.osgi.core and that you won't have to install by yourself.

---

**Solution 1**: You can install **camel-core** by hand by inserting following to the Karaf console:

```
feature:repo-add mvn:org.apache.camel.karaf/apache-camel/2.14.3/xml/features
feature:install camel-core
```

After this your bundle installation will succeed.

---

**Solution 2**: You can create Karaf archive (.kar) that will group all your required dependencies to one file that you can deploy. Create new Maven project with structure like this:

```
.
├── pom.xml
└── src
    └── main
        └── feature
            └── feature.xml
```

Where pom.xml is

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>osgi-example-kar</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<packaging>kar</packaging>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.karaf.tooling</groupId>
                <artifactId>karaf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.karaf.tooling</groupId>
            <artifactId>karaf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

and feature.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<features xmlns="http://karaf.apache.org/xmlns/features/v1.2.1" name="osgi-example-features">
    <repository>mvn:org.apache.camel.karaf/apache-camel/2.14.3/xml/features</repository>

    <feature name="osgi-example-features" version="1.0-SNAPSHOT"
         description="Features for running simple OSGi example.">

        <feature version="2.14.3">camel-core</feature>
    </feature>
</features>
```

When you run **mvn install** and copy target/*.kar file to Karaf deploy folder Karaf will install camel-core for you. After this your bundle installation will succeed.

---

Please note that when you log to System.out it will not appear on Karaf console log, so don't expect to see those messages there. You can use e.g. Log4j Logger there.